# The Google Maps layers button does not show as decribed by Google support at http://maps.google.com. How to display it?

Tags: google-maps

I do not have the layers button at http://maps.google.com as described here https://support.google.com/mymaps/answer/3024933?hl=en
and the layers shown here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AE-Al5mNu44

Attaching a screenshot of what I see.[image]

I am using a Windows desktop PC.

Comment: What browser are you using? Please [edit] your question.